# How to draw the circular progress bar in Chart.js Or any other JavaScript library in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, fusioncharts

For your reference I have attached the reference image link

[image: need to draw like this]

I am trying to achieve using this [samples found](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/), but I'm not able to give the arrow.

Comment: It might be quite tricky to overwrite plugin options. If your page isn't based on many progress bars you can create your own. It will give you more customization options. There should be many ready pure css examples with you can use as an base for your own creation. The only tricky thing which you will have to do it is to add the arrow and make it display dynamically. If you don't need scalling one it should be easy tho.

Comment: I need to create many progress bar as now the count is 4. It may be increase later. Which one is best is there any library for support or we need to create it own

Comment: I don't have any ready solution for this but the first thing which comes to my mind is to take a simple circle progress bar plugin, add it to page and then add a wrapper around it ( div ) with same width and height as your progress bar and a border-radius: 1000px. Now you should have a circle around your progress bar and the hard part starts. With css ::after you could add an arrow and dynamically set it position around this circle. If you would have an image you would need to find a good trajectory for it.

The other solution which seems right is just to write it from zero by yourself.

Comment: It's not the best solution but rather some kind of workaround if you prefer to stay with plugin for circle progress bars

Comment: Thanks @AdrianSawicki let me check the options

Comment: @AdrianSawicki do u know any javascript lib to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone have a better solution for this. Here is [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mxjj6jom/6668/).
It's quite crude solution and you would have to check how should arrow modify around circle. What I'm meaning is to write a function which will modify rotation and position of arrow pointer (so a bit of math). It's basically just adding `::after` with image of your pointer to the circle progress. About a plugin to use, there isn't any better or worse one, it should work with any. I've used progressbar.js for a static example. I hope it will help you at least a bit.